# I'm getting a read access violation when I try to train my decision tree using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

[Error Assertion Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGdV.png)

I've been getting this issue using data I pulled from a CSV file but even when I use blank Mats (like in the code below), I'm still getting the issue, so I don't think that's what my issue was...

I'd appreciate any help in understanding what I'm not doing right. I'm using OpenCV 4.2.0

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

void main()
{
    auto X = cv::Mat::zeros(400, 2, CV_32F); //dummy features matrix
    auto Y = cv::Mat::zeros(400, 1, CV_32S); // dummy label matrix
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> tData = cv::ml::TrainData::create(X, 0, Y);

    cv::ml::DTrees* dtree = cv::ml::DTrees::create();

    dtree->train(tData); // <- read access violation
}
```

**EDIT:** added an image of the error and console output, also the error has changed from Read Access Violation to an Unhandled Exception.

Comment: Add the exact error line to your question

Comment: The assertion refers to matrix data `type`. Are you sure you are using real (`float`) numbers in your training data?

Comment: I thought by specifying `CV_32F` in my Mat construction, that they were floats.Even where I was reading from a CSV, I was using `stof()`